# Solve for $x$ in the following figure, given that $AM=MC$

Tags: geometry, triangles

I need to find $x$ in the following figure

[image]

My progress: I tried to draw some auxiliary lines but I was unsuccessful. In geogebra I discovered an interesting relationship: $\triangle AFC$ is rectangle. An equation is still missing[image]

Comment: A rectangle? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Use $\cot m-n$ theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar diagram to yours but instead of $BD$, I have $BN$ which is perpendicular to $AB$.

[image]

$\angle CBF = 60^0, \angle CBM = \angle NBM = 15^0$

Also I will use $BC = a, AC = b, AB = c$.

In $\triangle NBC$, by angle bisector theorem,

$\cfrac{BN}{a} = \cfrac{NM}{b/2} \tag1$

We also have $\triangle ABN \sim \triangle AFC$

$\cfrac{AN}{b} = \cfrac{BN}{CF} = \cfrac{c}{AF}\tag2$

Now $CF = \cfrac {\sqrt3 \ a}{2}, BF = \cfrac {a}{2}$

From $(2)$, $BN = \cfrac{\sqrt3 \ a}{2b} AN$ and from $(1)$, $NM = \cfrac {b}{2a} {BN} \ $

So, $NM = \cfrac{\sqrt3}{4} AN$

$AN + NM = \cfrac{b}{2} \implies AN = \cfrac{2 b}{4 + \sqrt3}$

From $(2)$, $\cfrac{2}{4+\sqrt3} = \cfrac{c}{c + a/2} \implies c = (2-\sqrt3) a$

So $AF  = c + \cfrac{a}{2} = \cfrac{5-2 \sqrt3}{2} a$

$\tan x = \cfrac{CF}{AF} = \cfrac{\sqrt3} {5-2 \sqrt3} \implies x \approx 48.43^0$

Comment: Very good...the answer of the book is $48,5^o$ Thankful for the help

Comment: ...That's the idea. Normally these Peruvian problems are solved by auxiliary lines

Answer (score 2):

From triangle $\triangle AMB$:

$$\frac{AM}{BM}=\frac{\sin105^\circ}{\sin x}\tag{1}$$

From triangle $\triangle BMC$:

$$\frac{MC}{BM}=\frac{AM}{BM}=\frac{\sin15^\circ}{\sin \angle C}=\frac{\sin15^\circ}{\sin (60^\circ-x)}\tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2):

$$\frac{\sin105^\circ}{\sin x}=\frac{\sin15^\circ}{\sin (60^\circ-x)}$$

$$\frac{\cos15^\circ}{\sin x}=\frac{\sin15^\circ}{\sin (60^\circ-x)}$$

$$\sin (60^\circ-x)=\tan15^\circ\sin x$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\cos x-\frac12\sin x=\tan15^\circ\sin x$$

$$\sqrt{3}=(1+2\tan15^\circ)\tan x$$

$$\tan x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1+2\tan15^\circ}$$

$$x=\arctan \frac{\sqrt{3}}{1+2\tan15^\circ}\approx 48.43^\circ$$

Comment: Right. You could also insert $\tan15°=2-\sqrt3$.